# Change content of spans when different span has class active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not sure if this question was answered before. I spend few hours looking for this, but with no luck.

Anyway, what I'm basically trying to do is to change a content of few spans, when another (let's call it main) span has class active. Imagine something like this:

```
<div class="arrow-left" id="prev"></div>
<span class="headline-p active" id="trail1">Trail 1</span>
<span class="headline-p" id="trail2">Trial 2</span>
<span class="headline-p" id="trail3">Trial 3</span>
<a class="arrow-right" id="next"></a>

<h3>Result <span id="result">1</span></h3>
<p>Test 1 = <span id="test1">1</span></p>
<p>Test 2 = <span id="test2">1</span></p>
<p>Test 3 = <span id="test3">1</span></p>
<h3>Gener result = <span id="g-result">10%</span></h3>
```

So, after clicking NEXT Trail 1 changes to Trail 2, and all values in spans (result, tests and g-result) change with it. When Trail 2 is active, Result 1 changes to Result 2, and Tests display different values.

My basic idea is to have class active changing on trails. But I'm not that good with jquery/js, so if someone has a better idea, I will gladly listen to it.

One more thing, the code above is a simplified version of what I have. I would like to get just working demo to play with.

Thanks in advance for the help! I would really appreciate any hints or fiddles.

Sorry for any mistakes, It's my first post and I'm not English native.

Comment: are you searching functionality like this https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 1):

You can mind about something like the code below, this cycles the active class to the next position and back to the first when you're in the last.

Run the code below, hope it helps:

```js
// Waiting the DOM's load
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = null;
  var aux = null;
  
  // Registering click event and it's callback to the 'next' caller
  $('#next').on('click', function() {
    // Getting the actual active span
    aux = $('.headline-p.active').attr('id').split('trail');
    // The position
    id = aux[1];
    
    // Some console debugs
    //console.info('Actual position: '+id);
    //console.log('Numvber of DOM nodes: '+$('.headline-p').length);
    
    // Removing the active class
    $('.headline-p:eq('+(id - 1)+')').removeClass('active');

    // If you're in the last, it changes to the first position
    if (id == $('.headline-p').length) {
      $('.headline-p:eq(0)').addClass('active');

    // Jump to the next
    } else {
      $('.headline-p:eq('+id+')').addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="arrow-left" id="prev">prev</div>
<br />
<span class="headline-p active" id="trail1">Trail 1</span>
<span class="headline-p" id="trail2">Trial 2</span>
<span class="headline-p" id="trail3">Trial 3</span>
<br /><br />
<a class="arrow-right" id="next" style="cursor:pointer">next</a>

<h3>Result <span id="result">1</span></h3>
<p>Test 1 = <span id="test1">1</span></p>
<p>Test 2 = <span id="test2">1</span></p>
<p>Test 3 = <span id="test3">1</span></p>
<h3>Gener result = <span id="g-result">10%</span></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Being on my phone will blocks me to write code but i msde the same logic last night for a personal project

1) use the same classes on every results to display ( like you did headline-p ) and add an active class to the result you want to be displayed

2) initialise a counter to 0 that you'll increment/decrement when clicking on next/prev

3) hide every trails and results without the class active, the 1st trail and result should be visible

4 ) get a list of every trails and results like `var trails = $(.trails)`

5 ) after clicking on next / prev, remove the active class like this `$(.trails)[i-1].removeClass('active)` ( i - 1 if you already incresead the counter, if your doing this before itll be i ) on both trails and res

6 ) then add the active class on the current trails and results element `$(.trails)[i].addClass("active")`( i + 1 if you ibx the counter after )

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach if you wish to achieve without any library:

Idea is very simple:

- On click of `headline-p`, update required `spans`.
- On `next` or `prev`, set `position` to `+1` or `-1` and just move to that index. To keep consistent flow, you can directly call click of this element.

Also, I have used `Array.from` which is a part of ES6. If you wish to support old browsers, use `[].prototype.slice.call` to get array from HTMLCollection.

```js
function registerEvents() {
  var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span[id^=trail]');
  for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      updateClass(this, updateSpan)
    })
  }

  var btns = document.querySelectorAll('#next, #prev');
  for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      setActiveElement(this.id === 'next' ? 1 : -1);
    })
  }
}

function setActiveElement(position) {
  var currentElement = document.querySelector('.headline-p.active');
  var allNodes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.headline-p'));
  var index = allNodes.indexOf(currentElement);
  currentElement.classList.remove('active');
  var nextIndex = index + position;
  nextIndex = nextIndex < 0 ? allNodes.length - 1 : nextIndex % allNodes.length;
  var nextEl = allNodes[nextIndex];
  nextEl.classList.add('active')
  nextEl.click();
}

function updateClass(el, callback) {
  document.querySelector('.headline-p.active').classList.remove('active');
  el.classList.add('active')
  callback && callback()
}

function updateSpan() {
  var result = document.querySelectorAll("[id$=result], [id^='test']");
  var selectedText = document.querySelector('span.active').textContent;
  selectedText = selectedText.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    result[i].textContent = selectedText;
  }
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  registerEvents();
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow-left" id="prev">prev</div>
<span class="headline-p active" id="trail1">Trail 1</span>
<span class="headline-p" id="trail2">Trial 2</span>
<span class="headline-p" id="trail3">Trial 3</span>
<div class="arrow-right" id="next">next</div>

<h3>Result <span id="result">1</span></h3>
<p>Test 1 = <span id="test1">1</span>
</p>
<p>Test 2 = <span id="test2">1</span>
</p>
<p>Test 3 = <span id="test3">1</span>
</p>
<h3>Gener result = <span id="g-result">10%</span></h3>
```